# Codeigniter: How should I list categories in my sidebar? Should I query on every pageload, or is there an accepted way to cache this data?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, categories

I'm building a small storefront in Codeigniter and I was wondering what the accepted way to list categories is.  Of course, making a query to the categories table on every pageload seems a little psychotic.  I'm currently using a templating scheme such that I would load `some_view` like

```
$data['page'] = 'some_view';
$this->load->view('index', $data);
```

where the `index` wraps the template around a call to `some_view`.  Is there a standard Codeigniter way of listing the categories, or should I pass the categories list into the `$data` array (via a database call) for every pageload?  I'd rather not hardcode the values in, but I suppose I can if it's necessary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at using http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/caching.html to cache the Db calls